# Service bus sas token working even after the expiry time

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sas

I was investigating access to a service bus done through SAS token. I converted the "se" ticks value from the token to actual date-time and found that to be 1 AM which was 1 minute from the time I observed. That means the token must expire in a minute. I was constantly sending messages to the service using the aforementioned Sas token and noticed that the send was happening even after 1 min had elapsed. The actual expiry happened and the "token expiry" error was thrown after 6 mins. i.e instead of 1:00:00, it happened at 1:05:00. Is there a default added by the service bus or am I missing something here?

I was using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus latest .net nuget package.

Comment: Assuming you are sending messages from your local machine, you will need to take `clock skewness` into consideration i.e. the difference in time on your local machine and the time on the servers where Azure Service Bus is running. That could be the reason for the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: @GauravMantri: The time is the same. Regardless of the time difference between my local machine and server, the token should expire in a minute. Do you mean that if I request a token with expiry for a minute and in my local machine and skew the clock to a large extent, the token lives for a longer time? That is a security issue, right? I believe the local machine's time should not have any influence on the token's life.

Comment: Let me try to explain. Let's say the time on your local machine is 1:00 PM UTC. When you generate the token with 1 minute expiry based on that time, then it will expire on 1:01 PM UTC. However it is quite possible that the time on the servers running Azure Service Bus is 12:55 PM UTC. This is what is clock skewness and that would cause the token to remain active for more duration than what you expected.

Comment: @GauravMantri: thanks for explaining. My local machine makes a call to a sas service that contacts the service bus and gets the token for me. Also, the expiry is requested for 1 min. Assuming that my sas token service and the azure service bus servers are running the same time, then this problem should not occur, right? I will now check the server time to make sure i have correct time in both the places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS tokens have an certain amount of clock skew, to account for machines having different set clocks.

I cannot find the exact allowed time for Azure ServiceBus, but Azure Blob Storage allows for 15 minutes clock skew in their SAS tokens.

> remember that you may observe up to 15 minutes of clock skew in either
> direction on any request.
> -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview